# Camel 2.10.3 version in Fuse

Tags: fuseesb

We have downloaded the latest version of FuseESBEnterprise-7.1.0.  But the camel version is 2.10.0.fuse-71-047.   How can we incorporate the Camel2.10.3 in FUSE

Comment: Can you mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Fuse Camel version "2.10.0.fuse-71-047" is based on the Apache Camel 2.10 branch. All the time we are syncing in fixes and changes on the Apache Camel branch to the Fuse branch. So at the point of time for a release we spend time hardening the code, and do additional testing etc.

As Fuse ESB Enterprise 7.1 was released in December 2012, that means the Fuse Camel version "2.10.0.fuse-71-047" has all the fixes/changes up till the point of the code freeze in December 2012.

So essentially that release has all the stuff from the Apache Camel 2.10.3 release.